# Can Django STATIC_ROOT point to path on another server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am using Django 4.0.1 in my project, and right prior to deploying my site, I am faced with the issue of handling my static files. Due to the limit of my server, I have decided to instead serve these static files via CDN.

I have already configured my `STATIC_URL` option in `settings.py`:

```py
STATIC_URL = 'assets/'
```

I am aware that in the Django documentation, they say that this url refers to the static files located in `STATIC_ROOT`. Of course, normally the latter is an absolute path on your server where the `collectstatic` command collects the static files and put them there, but I am wondering if I can configure this `STATIC_ROOT` to point a path which is not on my server.

To be precise, I want to know whether I can point `STATIC_ROOT` to my CDN storage. In that way I can still use `STATIC_URL` to refer to my static assets, while being able to serve them via CDN.

Comment: Also [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production) say that Django is not supposed to serve static or media files on production and you should configure your webserver (nginx, apache) to handle static and media files URLs thus pointing to external server is not a django-settings related problem - just configure your webserver and rewrite/redirect wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's actually a recommended way to serve static files for years. Not sure why Django didn't add it to its core.

You can use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), it supports almost every cloud provider. You can use it for `media` and/or `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you can use it for any other server. For example while we use `AWS S3` as a server to serve static files it should look like this :

```py
USE_S3 = os.getenv('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```